# Анимация gif изображения на C#

Tags: c#, winforms, анимация, графика, gif

В программировании я новичок. Пытаюсь разобраться в работе класса ImageAnimator.
**Нужно *не используя pictureBox* вывести на форму анимированное изображение из готовой gif картинки** (или из ее отдельных кадров).
Как результат - на экране должны быть анимированные пчелки, которые перемещаются по экрану.
Логика перемещения уже сделана. Она состоит в том, что в классе пчелы есть метод Live, который вызывается в таймере формы.
Логика отрисовки пчел на данный момент такова: в классе формы создается объект класса `Bee` (то есть пчела) вместе с рандомными координатами.
`for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)                                                                                            new Bee(new Point(rand.Next(50, Width - 100), rand.Next(50, Height - 50)));`
Затем в методе `Draw(Graphics g)` класса Bee  пишется следующее:
`g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(coords.X - 64 / 2, coords.Y - 64 / 2, 60, 50));` image - изображение пчелы, которое берется из каталога программы с помощью `Image.FromFile(...);` 
Далее, в событии `Form1_Paint` проходим по всем сущностям (entity - базовый класс) и вызываем метод отрисовки:
`foreach (var entity in Entity.GetAll())  entity.Draw(e.Graphics);`
Таким образом у меня отрисовываются все объекты программы.
Но так пчелки не анимированные. Я взяла пример из [документации microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageanimator.animate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-drawing-imageanimator-animate(system-drawing-image-system-eventhandler)), он прекрасно работает (за исключением мигания изображения, которое не убирается включением двойной буферизации), но интегрировать его в свой код мне сложно. Основная проблема состоит в том, что в примере запускается `Application.Run(new animateImage());` - форма, в которой и писался код анимации, а у меня он записан в Form1. Соответственно, у меня должно быть `Application.Run(new Form1());`, но почему-то анимированное изображение не появляется на форме.

Comment: `Application.Run(new Form1());` он у вас уже есть в файле **Program.cs**, у вас уже есть готовый `Main`, не нужно еще один добавлять. Делайте всё остальное.

Comment: Добавьте в конструктор формы : SetStyle(
   ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
   ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
   ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true); - это должно убрать мерцание